# Google Sheets Sum of Query results on another sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create total figures from data imported from the results of a query from a different sheet. The query I am currently using is:

```
=QUERY('Reporting-Weekly'!A1268:N2910,"SELECT * WHERE N = '6A'")
```

which brings in a table like this [image: attached].

Exactly what I want, however, I want to be able to calculate the totals of the relevant columns however I am unable how to figure out how to do this, I either get a result of 0 or an error as can be seen in D2.

All information I have seen has not shown how to do this sum for multiple calculations in the one table.

Comment: What formula are you trying to sum a column?

Comment: It looks as if your column has strings rather than values, which makes it difficult to calculate a sum. If you hover over the #VALUE error, you will get more context.

Answer (score 0):

Ben Collins has an answer for this question:

https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/query-total-row/

In effect, you add another query to your query and append it to the bottom of your query using array referencing ({curly brackets})

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the values are probably strings. You can use this formula to first cast them to numbers, then compute the sum.

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(range)))
```